# Primary Decomposition Theorem clarification

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am missing something that I imagine is glaringly obvious with the primary decomposition theorem applied to a finitely generated torsion module over a PID.  From my reading of the theorem, the following should be true, but is obviously incorrect.  What am I not seeing?

Take $\mathbb{Z_6}$ as the finitely generated torsion module over $\mathbb{Z}$.  This has order $\mu = 6 = p_1*p_2=2*3$, where $2$ and $3$ are distinct nonassociate primes in $\mathbb{Z}$.  Then $\mathbb{Z_6} = (\mu$/$p_1)$$\mathbb{Z_6}$ $\oplus$ $(\mu$/$p_2)$$\mathbb{Z_6}$ = $3\mathbb{Z_6}$ $\oplus$ $2\mathbb{Z_6}$.

This is obviously not correct.

The relevant part of the theorem, stated from Roman:

Let $M$ be a (finitely generated) torsion module over a PID $R$, with order $\mu = p_1^{e_1}...p_n^{e_n}$ where the $p_i$'s are distinct nonassociate primes in $R$.  Then $M = M_{p_i}$  $\oplus$  ...  $\oplus$  $M_{p_n}$ where $$M_{p_i} = (\mu/{p_i}^{e_i})M = \{v \in M  \mid p_i^{e_i}v = 0\}.$$

Clarification would be appreciated.  Sorry if this is completely trivial.

Comment: You should not use acronyms (here PID) without writing them out at the first usage.

Comment: $(3, 2)$ is a generator for $3\mathbb{Z}_6 \oplus 2\mathbb{Z}_6$ of order $6$.

Comment: PID is a fairly standard acronym in algebra (stands for principal ideal domain).

Answer (score 2):

Actually, that really was a bad question.  After thinking a little bit more, it looks like my confusion involved the definition of a direct sum more than the theorem itself.  The example obviously checks out as stated.  Carry on.